# What is the purpose of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers

I'm used to find answers in books and manuals. I post here when I think a question can only be answered by someone who has gone through my doubts already and figured them out.

I've noticed my questions don't get answered nor does any already posted question I was interested in. I confess this annoys me a bit.

It seems the SE community prefers questions with easy answers (like this hot question [How to find the eigenvectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274241/how-to-find-the-eigenvectors)) and avoids more specific questions.

I think this is due to the whole reputation and point system which encourages users to answer only easy, well known, questions just **to get some points**.
Furthermore, people here are volunteers so they are justified in not challenging themselves answering questions that involve any kind of efforts. 
I understand this, and accept this (but I don't like it).

We all know SE is not a place where you can fully learn about anything, it's just a complement or a starting point, like Wikipedia.

But since general knowledge can be googled easily and since nobody on SE tries to extend this knowledge, what's the point of SE? It is useful only for people who ask common questions or don't feel like reading books or manuals?
Imagine your are an expert in your field, would you find SE useful?

There is always something to learn and browsing SE is fun and satisfies my curiosity but when I come for answers I never find them.

Comment: If you want more detail than you already included, I think you need to mention specific sites that concern you.  While the purpose is ultimately the same, the right answer is going to vary depending on the site.  For example, Stack Overflow is about answer questions to **specific** programming problems.  Questions soliciting feedback, listing pros & cons, discussions, etc are not really on-topic for SO.  Other sites have similar limits based on their own scopes.

Comment: This is too broad; the 140+ sites in the network can't be painted with the same brush. It's true that [math.se] is mostly about doing homework for people who did not read their textbook; questions that are not homework are usually ignored.

Comment: The benefit of many SE sites is that you can get expert answers, which you can seldom get by Googling. In theory, this is what SE is about. Easy questions often get more attention, but popularity doesn't always correlate with quality.

Comment: You may want to edit [your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1273277) and fix grammatical errors in it. Well researched questions who show care are usually better accepted.

Comment: @Nemo, thanks. I found two typos. English is my second language. Would you please help me find the other errors that prevent that question from deserving an answer?

Comment: As an example of SE community behavior take the downvoting of this question. I've tried to not being rude or impolite and I think I asked for a constructive critic. Please correct me if I am wrong so I can improve my questions. What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Downvote arrow lists reasons, such as "the question is not useful". Which is why I downvoted.

Comment: @Yes isn't it just a matter of taste? Can't this question make someone more willing to ask on a specific forum instead of here for example? Knowing some questions are less likely to be answered is useful to me.

Comment: @knm241, downvoting here on Meta is different. I got some questions quite downvoted too, don't feel too bad about it. :)

Comment: Yes,  it's a matter of opinion. Those who think the question is useful can upvote, and those who think it is useless can downvote. The total score represents a sort of an aggregate opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1273277) question which was asked 23 hours ago.

Sorry you didn't get an answer yet.  Most people who participate in SE find it useful. People have lives and don't wait around, F5'ing the questions page on Friday night/Saturday mornings just in hopes of answering your question.

There are plenty of mechanisms built into SE to give your question vibility in the future if the need exists.

Comment: In my opinion this is the most sane answer so far, it is along the lines of "We do our best" and that's what a mature community should think.

Comment: I think part of the pain some new users feel is due to the culture shock. As much as there are orientation pages and general guidelines, some of the communication rules and expectations are still under the table or take some practice by the user to perceive. It also takes some paradigm shifts on the part of the user. I left and came back to Stack Overflow several times until things started to click. I'm not sure if there is any way to resolve this: what is common sense to one person or a group may not be common sense to someone else.

Answer (score 7):

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) is built around a community of expert users.

[image]

The relevant text:

> **Expert communities.**
>
> Each of our 142 communities is built by people passionate about a focused topic.

Can you find loads of information on the Internet? Sure. But can you get *high-quality* information from reputable sources interpreted by folks who know what they're doing *just* from a Google search? I think not. That's one of the cool things about Stack Exchange. You can get answers from experts no matter what level you're at - and sometimes just [talk](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) with them.

I think that's the point of Stack Exchange. It's not just for general knowledge questions.

---

> It seems SE community prefer questions with easy answers (like this hot question [How to find the eigenvectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274241/how-to-find-the-eigenvectors)) and avoid more specific questions.

Not really. The community prefers questions that have good titles and are easy to understand. Quoting from [a similar discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6303/the-secret-to-getting-a-massive-reputation-is),

> I guess that as the site attracts a wider audience the answers that get the most upvotes are going to be the simple ones that everyone can understand. It does detract a bit from the usefulness of the reputation system though.

The question and answers there do discuss the latter sentence a lot, and you can also find related discussions on meta.SE. My message here, though, is the first bit.

Also, look at things probabilistically. There are clearly less people who are knowledgeable about more advanced stuff than people who are knowledgeable about more basic stuff. This means that, on average, a lower percentage of people will be able to potentially answer a given question if it is harder, and so it will attract fewer views and/or have a lower probability of it being seen and answered by the right person (or people).

Comment: But being passionate doesn't make you an expert. Thinking you can find high quality information only and only on SE is reductive in my opinion.

Comment: The point of SE is to build a community made of experts in order to do... what? Answer the questions they like the most?  Answer the question that will make SE shine the most? Will experts answer questions without the reputation system? I'm not complaining here, just trying to do some gedankenexperiment

Comment: @knm241 First comment: That was SE's phrasing, not mine. Second comment: Answer questions. People pick which ones they want. There are different motivations for answering questions (sorry to quote Physics again, but http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/why-do-users-answer-questions). I honestly have no good answer for that issue.

Comment: I'm interested in your very own personal opinion :) If it is appropriate may ask you: What do **you** think is the **actual** / **perceived** purpose of SE based on **your** experience? It is consistent with the official statement "Answering all users questions"? As your linked question points out there are different motivations, but, in your opinion, which one is the motivation of the common SE user? In my experience it is no longer more helping users.

Comment: @knm241 I think there are four types of users: learners, teachers, learners-and-teachers, and uncategorizable. The first group may just care about getting a quick answer, or they may care about learning a lot about a given subject. From their perspective, SE is a place to learn. The second group generally gets a kick out of helping others or teaching others. The third group consists of those who know about some things but not others. They ask and answer in moderation. The last group is everyone else (I don't know the size). (Comment continued).

Comment: I lump myself in the first group, which I think is the biggest. I answer far more than I ask, but I always learn from my answers. In many cases, I don't know much before answering, while in others, I can write something up off the top of my head. But I always learn something. This is a small sub-group of the first group, I would guess.

Comment: I share your view, I would only add a fifth group: the gamers. And I honestly don't known how big it is.

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of SE is [not to answer your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259263/why-is-se-so-disingenuous-about-its-purpose), but to build a library of questions and answers. Presumably for the normal motive of any company in a capitalistic market economy.